# How do I make the point label match the bar colour in jqplot?

Tags: colors, bar-chart, jqplot

I have a jqplot barchart rendering correctly. The chart has 2 series of data, one is is rendered blue and the other is rendered red. When I enable the pointLabels plugin to output the bar value above the bar the text is rendered in the default page font colour. I would like the font to use the colour of the bar each time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the point labels are given classes based on their series. So point labels in the first series will have a class called `jqplot-series-0`, the second series will have `jqplot-series-1` and so on. Just target them with some CSS and it should work.

```
.jqplot-series-0 {
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: This works for the color.  However `font-size` is ignored.  I wonder how to set the font-size for point labels.  Using `fontSize` in jqPlot pointLabel options does not work either.

Comment: @Stefan pointLabel font-size style is defined in `.jqplot-point-label` class.